# Angular best practice for sharing single API call between two active components

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out what the best practice is for the following situation:

I have two components A and B which are both are integrated on one page. Both components need access to data set C. Data set C is received by an API Call from the server. It should only be received initially and not twice for every component.

My first approach was using observables, but then the API call was done twice. So i switched to BehaviourSubjects, but when called from the controller the initial value was of course null. So i replaced it with ReplySubjects, which are working fine. But im struggling with the intial call. I got it working fine but im looking for the best pracice. Here is the code:

Component A and B are similar

```
getDataC(): void {
    this.dataCService.getData().subscribe(data=>{this.data = data})
}
```

I want to have the data in my service as well, so i can make a UPDATE on the API with the object to modify the data on the Server. My approach is working fine, but im not sure if i have to subscribe inside my service the this variable or keep it clean.

Then my Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataCAPIService } from '../resources/resources.service'
import { Observable, of, BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataCService {


    public dataC = new ReplaySubject<any>(1)
    dataCInsideService: any

    constructor(private dataCAPIService: DataCAPIService) {

    }


    getDataCAPICall() {
        if (this.dataC.observers.length < 2)
            this.dataCAPIService.getAll({}).subscribe(data => {
                this.dataC.next(data);
                this.dataC.subscribe(data => this.dataCInsideService = data)
            })
    }

    getData() {
        this.getDataCAPICall();
        return this.dataC;
    }


    saveDataC() {
        this.dataCAPIService.update(this.dataCInsideService, {}).subscribe(data => {
            this.dataC.next(this.dataCInsideService);
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks for any opinions or solutions to a better style.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two components A and B which are both are integrated on one
> page. Both components need access to data set C.

As long as they are being used in one page, why you are calling them from each components? I think you can call it from the page component and send it to children.

Children can get the data using `@Input()` decorator. You can send the data directly or you can send it as observable (it's fine if it is behavior subject or subject).

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer blackiii, im asking more for a best practice approach and this is just an example. I don't want to use it as a children with the Input operator. Its more about using two unrelated components to each other and using the same data. So that the data gets only called once and not more than that. I want to reuse this for specific use-cases where you need this. EG having a user object which is used by more components but only gets updated from the user himself.

Comment: Yes, that ReplySubject is the easiest and matching solution for your case. It's bit complicated but this kind of thing should be done using state management system, like Ngrx. That will be more professional than creating multiple services and reply subject variables.